# how can i customize gitlab page domain

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

On gitlab page it will always give you a domain name such as 
https://gitlab.com/username/projectname/pages/domains

BUT I WANT something like

https://thedomainiwant.com

what i should do

when i click New Domain on gitlab page it says something i do not understand

New Pages Domain:

Certificate (PEM) :
Upload a certificate for your domain with all intermediates
Key (PEM) :
Upload a private key for your certificate

Comment: [This](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_three.html) may help you